# Will upgrading to Mountain Lion allow USB Boot?

Tags: usb, startup

One problem I have with my 2009 MBP running 10.6.8 Snow Leopard is that I can't boot from USB (well, I can, but only OS X in certain formats). I would really like to be able to boot linux from USB at will. I have heard this is possible on newer macs. Would this be possible for me if I were to update?

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook from 2007 and it's possible to boot from USB without a problem.

Simply hold down - Option Key / (Alt) on Windows Keyboard on Boot and select where to boot from.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310

If it doesn't work you might have to do a EFI Update

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3260

Comment: What version os OS X are you running? Can you boot Ubuntu, or another "legacy operating system" ? 

The last I read OS X (at least Snow Leopard) considered anything that wasn't OS X on an HFS+ partition to be a "legacy" system and refused to boot from it.

There are elaborate workarounds, but this would be a major selling point for ML for me.

Comment: I run 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 an switch between them.

Never tried Lynx but should be possible aswell with BootCamp maybe even with the EFI Bootloader never tried. Only saw a lot of people with linux on ther MBP

Comment: Installing linux is no problem via CD drive, it's booting from a Linux live USB.